# GSON to server in url format?

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, gson

I have converted my java objects to json format.

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("D****"); 
String ipAddress= address.getHostAddress();

Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(ipAddress);
System.out.println();
```

I need to get the json value to server url format, eg: `localhost:8080/json` 
so that I can get that value from the ajax url.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

I used spring MVC to do this:

[Here is the link](http://hmkcode.com/spring-mvc-json-json-to-java/)